# Spring-security - AccessDecisionVoter-impl wont be invoked

Tags: java, spring-security, voting

I am trying to create custom AccessDecisionVoter and just stop it in the debugged when it gets invoked.

I have put a breake point in each method, but nothing happed.

**spring-security.xml:**

```
<bean id="accessDecisionManager" class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.UnanimousBased">
  <property name="decisionVoters">
     <list>
          <bean class="com.affiliates.server.security.voters.VoterTest">
              <property name="brandsApi"  ref="brandsApi"/>
          </bean>
        </list>
  </property>
```

**IBrandsApi.java**

```
    public interface IBrandsApi {

    IHibernateBean getByPK(Integer id);

    @Secured({ "ROLE_BRAND_ADMIN" })    
    IHibernateBean update(IHibernateBean brand);

    @Secured({ "ROLE_BRAND_ADMIN" })    
    IHibernateBean insert(IHibernateBean brand);

    @Secured({ "ROLE_BRAND_ADMIN" })    
    ResultContainer getAll(IFilter filter);

    @Secured({ "ROLE_ADMIN" })  
    Integer delete(IFilter filter); 
}
```

**VoterTest.java (empty file with break points)**

```
    public class VoterTest implements AccessDecisionVoter {
private IBrandsApi brandsApi;

    public IBrandsApi getBrandsApi() {
        return brandsApi;
    }

    public void setBrandsApi(IBrandsApi brandsApi) {
        this.brandsApi = brandsApi;
    }

        @Override
        public boolean supports(ConfigAttribute attribute) {
            System.out.println("here");
            return false;

        }

        @Override
        public boolean supports(Class<?> clazz) {
            System.out.println("here");
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public int vote(Authentication authentication, Object object,
                Collection<ConfigAttribute> attributes) {
            System.out.println("here");
            return 0;
        }
    }
```

BTW, there were no exceptions thrown during app loading / running
Thanks

Comment: Do you have <global-method-security secured-annotations="enabled" /> ?

Comment: yes, I am able to use annotation and @Autowire spring beans, thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use your custom AccessDecisionManager, otherwise the default one is used. You can do this with

```
<global-method-security access-decision-manager-ref="accessDecisionManager"/>
```

Take a look at [the documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/ns-config.html#ns-access-manager) for more information on this.

One more thing: The `supports()` methods in your voter should probably return `true` otherwise `vote()` won`t be called.